# Jquery+wcf. Problem with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, authentication, http-headers

My service is secured with basic authentication set in IIS and i am try to get data from service with Jquery.

Cross domain calls is enabled.

I have next request headers

```
Host http:\\service.com
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection keep-alive
Origin null
Access-Control-Request-Me... GET
Access-Control-Request-He... authorization
Pragma no-cache
Cache-Control no-cache
```

Responses

```
Content-Type text/html
Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate Basic realm="172.27.131.5"
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
Access-Control-Allow-Head... *
Date Fri, 12 Aug 2011 08:07:29 GMT
Content-Length 1293
```

Code

```
 $.ajax({
     headers : {
        "Authorization" : "Basic TVNF3TQtU1BGMjAx6C12bVxzbW4ydHBvaW50OlF3Z5J0eSEyM6Q1"
     },
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
      alert('ok!');
      formatData(format_type,data);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
     }
  });
```

also i tried to set

```
 beforeSend : function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password));
        },
```

But i have next error:

Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: try the ajax call without the `headers`

Comment: So how service will authentificate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the following code to the global.asax in your WCF project (only works when hosted in iis):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Jquery issues an OPTIONS call to the WCF service to check if the call is allowed. You'll have to match the exact header. You can also download an example here: http://sameproblemmorecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/creating-secure-restfull-wcf-service.html.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable the cross domain in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     headers : {
        "Authorization" : "Basic TVNF3TQtU1BGMjAx6C12bVxzbW4ydHBvaW50OlF3Z5J0eSEyM6Q1"
     },
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     crossDomain:true, <--
     xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     }, 
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
      alert('ok!');
      formatData(format_type,data);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.tejastank.com/moderator/v1/series?key='+key,
    data: myData,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Solve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error modifying the dataType parameter to `dataType:'jsonp'` and adding a `crossDomain:true`.